# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable error with ChromeDriver and Chrome using Selenium on macos

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, typeerror

When I try to test my test application to see if Selenium Chrome is working, I get this error:

```
driver= webdriver.chrome("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
 TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I checked if it is installed

```
/usr/local/bin/chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 84.0.4147.30 (48b3e868b4cc0aa7e8149519690b6f6949e110a8-refs/branch-heads/4147@{#310})
```

But I still get errors even after restarting my computer.

My environment is:

- Mac OS Catalina (10.15.6)
- Chrome version:  84.0.4147.89
- PyCharm Pro

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class `webdriver.Chrome` is case sensitive. Right now, you get this error because you are, inadvertently, trying to call the module `webdriver.chrome`.

If you change your code to

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
```

you should no longer get this error.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

...implies that there was a [typeerror](/questions/tagged/typeerror) calling the `chrome` module.

---

As per your code attempt you have used:

```
driver= webdriver.chrome()
```

Here [python](/questions/tagged/python) interprets `chrome` as a submodule of `webdriver`:

[image: chrome_module]

---

### Solution

Instead you need to call [`selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chrome/selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.html#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver) Class method as follows preferably using the *key* `executable_path` as follows:

```
driver= webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
                  ^ note the uppercase C
```

Answer (score 0):

driver= webdriver.chrome("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")

This should be driver= webdriver.**Chrome**("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")